# HTML: Who takes care show/hide the scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I read some online articles and they say that **html** tag represent the browser window, so **html** is equals to the browser window size. If the **body** size is greater than the **html** size, then the scrollbar will show up. So it is the **html** element that controls to display the scrollbar or not.

It's like in this picture:

[image]

You may think of it like:

```
html { overflow: auto; }
```

So if want to hide the scroll bar on purpose, I would do:

```
// myCSS.css
html { overflow: hidden;// override default }
```

If I want to scroll to a position of the body:

```
var position = 500;
$('html').animate({scrollTop: position}, 1000);
```

This sounds all promising. But I used FireBug to check the height of the **html** tag, they are always greater or equal than the size of **body**. (Assuming a default webpage with no css, and contents in body exceed window size) The **html** tag size is not really the size of the browser window, and it is more of the size of **body** element.

So where does the scrollbar really come from? How does the scrollbar really work?

Comment: nothing has to take care of the scrollbar. If the content is bigger than the window size, then it will appear. It's done in the browser itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read some online articles and they say that html tag represent the
>   browser window, so html is equals to the browser window size. If the
>   body size is greater than the html size, then the scrollbar will show
>   up. So it is the html element that controls to display the scrollbar
>   or not.

That's very wrong indeed.¹

What the [CSS 2.1 Spec section 9.1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#viewport) says is

> When the viewport is smaller than the area of the canvas on which the
>   document is rendered, the user agent should offer a scrolling
>   mechanism.

Yet that doesn't seem quite correct either, since a scroll is not generally provided to move the viewport over areas of the canvas that have a negative x or negative y value, even if content is painted there.

The best I can establish is that the scroll bars are made available to move the viewport over the areas of the canvas which have a rendered box for 0 or positive x and y co-ordinates.

Whatever, neither the size of the html element box, nor the body element box are special. They are just rendered boxes on the canvas, the same as other elements. Other elements may be rendered outside those boxes, because of overflow or absolute positioning and the scroll mechanism will take the full size of those elements into account.

An example and diagram may help understanding. Consider this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Scroll limits</title>
    <style>
      html { padding:20px; border:1px green solid; height:80px; }
      body { margin:0; border:1px black solid; height:150px; }
      #div1 { position:absolute; top:-50px; height:65px; left:-50px; 
              width: 65px; background-color:blue; }
      #div2 { position:absolute; top:200px; height:65px; left: 110%; 
              width: 65px; background-color:yellow; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    body
    <div id="div1">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">div 2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPWuj/)

results in this:

[image: Scrollable area]

---

<sub>¹ The online article probably, and the picture in the question definitely, come from http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html. It should be noted that that article was written in 2004. In 2004, what the then draft CSS 2.1 said didn't really matter. What mattered was what IE6 did, and the article *does* describe what IE6 did.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
html {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling has to do with `overflow`. When the `body` overflows the `document.documentElement` *(the html element)* the scollbar/bars appear. While other Elements' `overflow` defaults to `visible` the `html` tag defaults to `scroll`. To answer your question, the scrollbar appears on the parent of the overflowing content, when the parent's `overflow` is set to `scroll`, in this case the `html` tag.