# What happens when setting scrollTop/scrollLeft on scroll event of an element with the css property ‘overflow’ set to ‘auto’?

Tags: javascript, css

What happens when setting scrollTop/scrollLeft on scroll event of an element with the css property `overflow` set to `auto`?

Comment: You can just try it out in any sandbox tool.

Comment: @vsync `visible` is the default not `auto`

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I was thinking of the `<body>` element only. There `auto` behavior is effectively applied

Comment: @vsync even for the `body` it's still visible and not auto .. what you are talking about is the viewport behavior. According to the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow) `if the value on the root element is 'visible'. The 'visible' value when used for the viewport must be interpreted as 'auto'` ...  so the viewport is obliged to have an auto overflow in case the root is having visible. A bit tricky but it's not about the `body` element, we may don't see the difference but there is a difference

Comment: @vsync here is some intresting questions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757841/html-who-takes-care-show-hide-the-scrollbar/19759281#19759281 / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640543/why-does-setting-overflow-x-hidden-on-html-cause-a-childs-position-stick/53642470#53642470

Answer (score 0):

To quote w3school on `overflow: auto`:

> If overflow is clipped, a scroll-bar should be added to see the rest of the content

vs what they say on the default value of `overflow: visible`:

> The overflow is not clipped. It renders outside the element's box. This is default

This means that when an element has overflow it will create a scrollbar instead of leaving the overflow leave the element.

Here is a snippet showing the difference

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.auto {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #ff2222;
}

/* This is the default */
.visible {

  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #22ff22
}
```

```html
<div class="auto">
  <p>I can scroll! LaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLa</p>
</div>

<!-- This is the default -->
<div class="visible">
  <p>I can't scroll! LaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLaLa</p>
</div>
```